# How do I post to Google Plus via PHP?

Tags: php, api, class, google-plus

I was wondering if there's already a floating unofficial PHP library or class that I can use to be able to post to user's Google Plus stream? I'm not talking about the new option on the +1 buttons. I only want it to publish to their stream and not with the +1 button method. Sorry if this has been asked already but I can't locate any question that has the same concept as mine.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Google+ is still in beta, I don't believe they have any sort of API available yet. You'll have to settle with Google Buzz feeds for now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. There is no API currently.

**Update**: Sept 15, 2011 saw the release of the Google+ REST API: https://developers.google.com/+/api/

Answer (score 2):

We definitely plan to involve developers and publishers in the Google+ project, but we don’t have specific details to share just yet. Please stay tuned and sign up to receive more information about Google+ developer opportunities. https://services.google.com/fb/forms/plusdevelopers/

Comment: Yeah sure! After almost 1 year and 6 months still no reliable API for Google+... no support for posting, events, etc... Tell Google to hire more software engineers to work on Google+!

Answer (score 2):

I found this site which seems to allow people to post to their user stream - http://www.d3.do/labs/circleoftrust/index.php

Comment: This is a comment, rather than an answer. How can you show this example that you gave to address the question?