# Directly share a post in Google plus

Tags: android, google-plus, google-play-services

I'm able to create Interactive post by using sample example, as below.

```
            Intent shareIntent = new PlusShare.Builder()
                    .setType("text/plain")
                    .setText("Welcome to the G+ platform.")
                    .getIntent();

            startActivityForResult(shareIntent, 0);
```

when the activity starts it shows up window where user have to press share button manually.
Is there any way to post directly to Google plus stream by adding default recipients(Public/to circle) without asking user to press Share button.

Answer (score 4):

For content that appears in a user's stream, that user must explicitly share it. Put another way, posting to the user's stream is to do something that the platform does not support. This is done by design because users want to be in control of what appears in their stream. Deceiving the user and posting to their stream or sharing without consent puts you in violation of the [Google+ developer policy](https://developers.google.com/+/policies) and your API client can be banned until you are compliant should you even find a way to do this.

More information and several related questions are:

- [Sharing on Google+ Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17715306/sharing-on-google-stream-after-authorisation) covers passively writing to Google with [app activities](https://developers.google.com/+/features/app-activities).
- [How do I post to Google+ from PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7252124/how-do-i-post-to-google-plus-via-php)
- [How to post to Google wall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7570327/how-to-post-in-google-plus-wall)
- [Google+ API for posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857812/google-plus-api-for-posting-on-wall-like-facebook)

Please post the feature request in the [Google+ platform issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/) and let the Google+ platform team know why you feel you should be able to do this.